# regex to match any capital or small letter for a fixed word

Tags: php, regex

I need to match the `abcd` in text which may contain:

`abcd`ssss

ffff`abcd`ksdks

`AbCd`fdjb

`aBCd`

In a nutshell any match is qualified which can match caps or no caps with the text with other text or as a seperate word

### EDIT

Environment : PHP

Comment: Which flavour of regexp are you using? Most have an "i" flag, which forces case insensitive searching. And you'd use the word boundary match to ensure standaloneness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your solution for PHP:

```
if (preg_match('/abcd/i', $subject)) {
    # Successful match
} else {
    # Match attempt failed
}
```

It finds `abcd` anywhere, including as part of a word, as you asked for. It is also case-insensitive due to the `i` suffix.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to search for the string `abcd` anywhere in the input (even as part of other word), you can use the regex

```
if(preg_match('/abcd/i',$input)) {
  // $input has abcd somewhere in some case.
}
```

But is you want `abcd` and not as part of other word, you can use:

```
if(preg_match('/\babcd\b/i',$input)) {
  // $input has abcd word somewhere in some case.
}
```

Comment: He asked for "**with other text** or as a seperate word" so \b won't help here...